# Disable URI validation in HTML Purifier

Tags: php, sanitization, htmlpurifier, html-sanitizing

For various reasons I would like to disable the URI validation in HTML Purifier, is this possible?

I realize the possible security implications this would have for many sites, but not actually in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by patching the source, replacing AttrDef_URI with a stub that does nothing. But this is super insecure.

Comment: No way without patching the source?